# bottom overflow for textinput after entering few lines flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I have a textfield widget that allows user to enter multiple lines, but after entering few lines, got overflow error as shown below.
[image: overflow example]

This happened because whenever there is new line, the textfield height increases and pushed down the keyboard. This is before entering new line.
[image]

I used `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,` to solve the problem where keyboard covers textfield but this doesn't seem to solve the problem above.

Is there any way I can push the textfield up after entering new line as shown below so that the keyboard the textfield won't overflow the keyboard?
[image]

This is my code

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class Detail extends StatefulWidget {
  const Detail({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Detail> createState() => _DetailState();
}

class _DetailState extends State<Detail> {
  final ScrollController scrollCtrl = ScrollController();
  bool isScrolled = false;
  bool isLoading = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bottom = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;
    AppBar appbar = AppBar(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      title: const Text('Approval Detail'),
    );
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      scrollCtrl.addListener(() {});
      scrollCtrl.position.isScrollingNotifier.addListener(() {
        if (!scrollCtrl.position.isScrollingNotifier.value) {
          setState(() {
            isScrolled = false;
          });
        } else {
          setState(() {
            isScrolled = true;
          });
        }
      });
    });
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage('images/bg_home.png'),
          fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        // resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        appBar: appbar,
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            SingleChildScrollView(
              controller: scrollCtrl,
              reverse: true,
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: bottom),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 200),
                        child: Text("Detail")),
                    Container(
                      height: 25,
                      color: columnColor,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            IndexedStack(
              index: isScrolled
                  ? 0
                  : 1, // switch between Foo and Bar based on condition
              children: [
                Container(),
                Positioned(
                    child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                      bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
                  child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, child: BottomWidget()),
                )),
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my BottomWidget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class BottomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  BottomWidget({
    Key? key,
    
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<BottomWidget> createState() => _BottomWidgetState();
}

class _BottomWidgetState extends State<BottomWidget> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 180,
      width: double.maxFinite,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.grey[300]!,
              offset: const Offset(0.0, 2.5),
              blurRadius: 1.0,
            ),
            const BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black12,
              offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
              blurRadius: 1.0,
            ),
          ],
          color: Colors.white,
          borderRadius:
              const BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(20.0))),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 15, 10, 0),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: double.maxFinite,
              // height: 45,
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 9,
                    child: TextField(
                      minLines: 1,
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                      maxLines: null,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                              borderSide: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFD6DDE1))),
                          focusedBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: cbossBlue),
                          ),
                          filled: true,
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFD6DDE1)),
                          hintText: "Add note here",
                          fillColor: Colors.white70),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.fullscreen),
                      onPressed: () {
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 15, 10, 0),
            child: Container(
              width: double.maxFinite,
              child: Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 5,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            border: Border.all(color: cbossBlue),
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2))),
                        height: 50,
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                          },
                          child: Center(
                              child: Text('Reject',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      color: cbossBlue,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Flexible(
                    flex: 5,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(2))),
                        height: 50,
                        child: InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                          },
                          child: const Center(
                              child: Text(
                            'Approve',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                color: Colors.white),
                          )),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: I have added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

Edit

I tried such solution for you. I think it will be simpler and easier to edit. I will shoot an emulator video and add it soon, at that time you can think of the solution. I hope it was able to answer your question.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: Stack(
              children: [
                ListView(
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      children: const [
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                        Text("Foo"),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                )
              ],
            )),
            TextField(
              minLines: 1,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              maxLines: 5,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFD6DDE1))),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    borderSide: const BorderSide(color: Colors.blue),
                  ),
                  filled: true,
                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xFFD6DDE1)),
                  hintText: "Add note here",
                  fillColor: Colors.white70),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text("Floating Texts")),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I think you wanted something like this :)
https://i.imgur.com/spxpZsZ.mp4

Comment: I can't use SingleChildScrollView because I am using Stack and use Positioned widget to position that textfield widget at the bottom of the screen. When I use stack, the textfield widget went to the top of the screen.

Comment: If not private can you share your code? Maybe I can help better that way.

Comment: I edited my post and added the code.

Comment: Oh sorry i Just understand your problem now. I Will try a solution asap and edit my answer. ^^

Comment: I think it's done now mate :)

Comment: Thanks a lot man, this is exactly what I was looking for, I will try to implement it in my code later and hopefully still work as expected.

Comment: You're welcome mate ^^ Feel free to ask anything, anytime. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to fix it is to wrap your form with `SingleChildScrollView` widget.

Comment: Shared my code, can't seem to wrap with SingleChildScrollView because my widget that I positioned at the bottom came on top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Share your widget tree so we can give you best solution.
for now, if you have a `Column` as root widget, replace it with `Listview`. this will fix your problem and make view scrollable when keyboard opened.
the widget tree will lock like something like this :

```
ListView(
  children:[
    widget1(),
     widget2(),
      .....
]
)
```

Comment: My widget tree is something like this
Scaffold( 
body: Stack(
children:[ SingleChildScrollView(child: content),Positioned(child: textfield widget)